# how to fix unexpected component declaration by module while running test?

Tags: angular, jestjs

I am trying to perform unit testing on my angular application which has two components. root AppComponent and a myFormComponent. I want to perform unit testing on the form fields available in the myFormComponent.

I have went through all the answers provided here but none seems to work for me. The answers provided are for problems while running the application but my problem is when i run the test using "npm run test".

//app.module.ts

```
  import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
    import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

    import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
    import { MyFormComponent } from "./my-form/my-form.component";
    import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

    @NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, MyFormComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

//my-form.component.spec.ts

```
    import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from 
    "@angular/core/testing";

    import { MyFormComponent } from "./my-form.component";
    import { DebugElement } from "@angular/core";
    import { By } from "@angular/platform-browser";
    import { AppComponent } from "../app.component";

    describe("MyFormComponent", () => {
    let component: MyFormComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyFormComponent>;

    let debugElement: DebugElement;
    let htmlElement: HTMLElement;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [MyFormComponent]
    }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyFormComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    fixture.detectChanges();

    // debugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("p"));
    // htmlElement = debugElement.nativeElement;
    });

    test("check dummy", () => {
    const res = 2 * 3;
    expect(res).toBe(6);
  });
});
```

Actually the test case should pass but its not happening. I am getting an error "Unexpected value 'MyFormComponent' declared by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.". When I remove the first "beforeEach" method, it seems to work.